# Jmeter 3.2- Error in NonGUIDriver org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterStopTestException

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2

I have a JMeter test suite, which is working fine till apache-jmeter-2.13.

When upgrade to JMeter 3.2 and I get below exceptions in non GUI mode.

I didn't do any change in the JMeterscript, why this error is throwing in JMeter versions later 2.13 or in version 3.2?

jmeter -n -t E:\testsuite.jmx -l E:\tmp\RORlogs.csv

```
Error in NonGUIDriver org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterStopTestException: ModuleCon
troller:Tracker_List_Artifacts has no selected Controller (did you rename some e
lement in the path to target controller?)
```

Test was shutdown as a consequence

Comment: For me the issue got resolved.

In earlier versions of jmeter 2.13, it wont validate the controllers which is disabled. But from Jmeter version 3.2, irrespective of disabling all the controllers should have proper target values. For me the issue got fixed once the proper target controller is assigned to disabled module controller.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Add an answer to close the problem:

In earlier versions of jmeter 2.13, it didn't validate the controllers which is disabled.

But from Jmeter version 3.2, irrespective of disabling all the controllers should have proper target values.

Fix the issue by assign proper target controller is assigned to disabled module controller.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you've got the exact same situation, but what we've found is that JMeter has a problem where if you have a script with a module controller that includes another script that also has a module controller the file paths may be off and so the module controller of the included script will error.

For example. Say I have 'main.jmx' that has a module controller that points to 'external.jmx'. 'external.jmx' has a module controller that points to 'another_script.jmx'.

'main.jmx' is located in 'Documents/scripts', and this is also the directory we lauched JMeter from. 'main.jmx' has a relative path that points to 'external.jmx'. However, 'another_script.jmx' does not have the same relative path and so JMeter throws an error.

Pro tip: renaming your test elements to descriptive names will make debugging scripts far easier (it looks like you've done this, but this is more for other people reading this).

Answer (score 0):

I am using Jmeter 5* and here irrespective of how many target controller names you modify, you finally need to touch all transactions/module controller from top to bottom once. Its kind of re-associating module controller with target controller. After that its working fine for me.